# SSO using Windows Identity Foundation and WCF

Tags: wcf, single-sign-on, wif, saml

We have a client with following existing product line

- Website1 (Uses form authentication using user information stored in SqlDB for website1)
- WebSite2 (Uses form authentication using user information stored in SqlDB for website2)
- WinApplication1 (uses Active Directory to authenticate user)

More products in line for future release.

They want to implement Single Sign on (SSO) for all their products with following features-

- Product list that will be accessing by a user will be depended on his/her role. 
        It should be configurable. Roles are being defined in DB having Fk relation 
        with user table.
- SSO service should be flexible to accommodate new product.
- should use SAML to sucure token.
- WinApplication1 has link for website1 and website2. If an user is login in WinApplication1
        and click on any links of website1/website2, user should able to access the sites without
         entering his credential.
- If user is logned in in any product that user should be all to access any other product
        he has access right without enterting userid/password.

**We have following query**

- We are planning to implement SSO using WCF and WIF. Can all above requirement be fulfill
        by using WIF.
- We want to keep user authentication part in respective product as each product has their
        own user store. OR WE SHOULD HAVE CENTRALIZED USER STORE?
- What shouldl be the responsibility of STS (implemented in WCF) in respect to SSO &
        security?

We have read lot about WIF from MSDN([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377151(VS.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377151%28VS.110%29.aspx), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx) could not find any solid article/sample giving some practical scenarios. Most of them about using local STS…may be it is my bad luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found a article that matches most of your requirements with practical implementation example.

The article describes an easy approach for programming against Windows Identity Foundation in a Single Sign-On (SS0) scenario from the angle of a relying party application. WIF supports a variety of Claims-based authentication scenarios but this document will focus upon using WIF to develop an application that supports SSO given the use of a SAML 2.0 token containing some basic claims.

Article also includes some part explaining about using roles in AD Users:

**http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/windows-identity-foundation-and-single-sign-on-sso/**

To impersonate the Original Caller in WCF Calling from a Web Application, you additionally need to follow:

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650591.aspx**

---

**Update**:

difference between IP-STS and FP-STS and how to choose where to put STSes in your architecture. You will learn about federation, home realm discovery and how to leverage the WIF extensibility model in order to handle multiple identity providers.

http://bit.ly/bTo3w4

How a generic web site can be enhanced with identity provider capabilities regardless of the authentication technology it uses, simply by adding an STS page. 
Another lab shows how to use an existing membership store for authenticating calls to a custom STS and sourcing claim values.

http://bit.ly/bQAQhA

**WIF and WCF**

http://bit.ly/8X63T5

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Pranav>> C-Sharpcorner article is using local STS and just showing how to get claim information. We need information how use STS where RP web site have their user information in their own DB.

Comment: It should be more easier than this since instead of using claims to retrieve user info from other sources like fb, twitter you have user info in your own Database. I have adding new link for comment.

Comment: What i am trying to do now now- i have created one WebSite_STS and configred local STS in it with default claim. Created another two website website1 & website2 and copied FederationMetadata.xml file from from Website_STS to root of both website & configured path in webconfig. Now when i run website1 or 2 it does not call Website_STS. Am i doing some thing wrong.

Comment: Please check if SSO setting are good for both websites & working.

Comment: If you want i can attached the sample. Config settings in RP site -<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms" />
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="http://localhost:61974/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:ProviderSelection" value="productionSTS" />
  </appSettings>
  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
----------